# Multiple button click event

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-button

I have two buttons and each button has each function, but also I would like to add another function when the user clicks these buttons at the same time. Here is  my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button1, button2;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
        textView.setText("Double Action");
        SPLogger.logMassage("Same", (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastClickTime) + "");
        return;
    }
    mLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SPLogger.logMassage("notSame", System.currentTimeMillis() + "");

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        textView.setText("Only First Action");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        textView.setText("Only Second Action");

    }
}
}
```

This code working almost, but I have one little issue. When I click for example the first button quickly, it's working like same time action. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?
also
What's the best way to check same time click in Android?
Thanks

Comment: This not way to perform second click by time managed. You need to manage this in `onTouch()` `listener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must check if the second click is from the other button than the first click, so you have to keep in a variable the last clicked button.
Example

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
private int mLastClickedID = -1;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastClickTime < 1000 && mLastClickedID !=v.getId()) {
        textView.setText("Double Action");
        SPLogger.logMassage("Same", (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastClickTime) + "");
        return;
    }
    mLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mLastClickedID = v.getId()
    SPLogger.logMassage("notSame", System.currentTimeMillis() + "");

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        textView.setText("Only First Action");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        textView.setText("Only Second Action");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it worked :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button1, button2;
private boolean buttonClicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!buttonClicked) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        buttonClicked = false;
                    }
                }, 100); //100ms 
            }
            else{

        Toast.makeText(this, "Both Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            buttonClicked=true;
            //do whatever functions you want here
            break;


        case R.id.button2:
            buttonClicked=true;
            //do whatever functions you want here
            break;

    }

}
}
```

**Hope this helps you !**

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work too :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String TAG = "myTag";
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - 200 >= lastClick){
        if(btn1.isPressed() && btn2.isPressed()){
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: both");
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: button 1");
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: button 2");
        }
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

The 200 millis time is to prevent onClick content being called two times